# If the world was flat, what would happen if someone walked off?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, gravity

A character jumps off the edge of the world in my sci-fi story. Would they float or would they just fall?

Comment: That totally depends on how your world works. There are some [examples](https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/Tethis) of characters just falling.

Comment: The issue with this question is you've perhaps misunderstood how we work (don't worry, it's only your first question). You'd need to tell us what you want to happen, then we can help you create/formalise the rules governing how it happens (or if it can). Please consult the [help] for guidance. I forgot to say, welcome to worldbuilding, enjoy the site.

Comment: Welcome! The answer to your question is completely dependent on how your world works (especially gravity). If you know what you want to happen, we can help you design some workable rules to make it happen. Alternatively, if you have a good idea of how your world's rules work, we can help you work out how it would apply to your overly adventurous character. Personally, I can think of rule sets that would cause everything from falling, floating, bouncing back, or even dissolving into the underlying structure of the universe. But that's just me and this isn't my question.

Comment: Hi Booknerd. I've voted to close your question as opinion-based. From our [help/on-topic], questions "must be specific and answerable, must include context, [and] must include restrictions/requirements." From this [help/dont-ask] page, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where every answer is equally valid [or] you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question." This is a classic but off-topic [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609).

Answer (score 3):

a planet sized flat disk in the real world would not exist. but if it were then you would only find that only the center of either side to feel flat. walking from the center to the edge would seam like walking up a ever increasing slope. it would be a vertical cliff near the edge. then when you reach the edge and climb on it it would be like a narrow strip of flattish ground with 2 small pieces of horizon and the drops either side. then you could walk all the way down hill to the center of the other side.

any liquid and gas would form a sphere around the center. this would be an ocean without islands. that has a small strip of livable land around it. any land based life would permanently live on the side of a hill.

Comment: Except for the lucky few who live directly over the middle. Life is normal there.

Comment: *"Life is"* what we think of as *"normal there"*

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how your gravity works! Here are two cases.

## Normal Gravity

If it works like normal gravity, the person actually walks more and more sideways as they approach the edge, since the center of mass is in the middle of the disk and the whole disk conspires to pull you there. This adventurer's "walking" looks more like "climbing" at the edge, so there really isn't any walking off.

If this adveturer goes off the edge, they might:

- hit the side of the disk. If so, it will be like reaching a large ledge in mountain climbing. They can quite comfortably stand there, since the whole world is under their feet!
- fall to the other side and are now on the (former) underside of the world. They will still fight gravity as it pulls them to the center of the disk, just like they were on the other side.
- jump far enough to go into orbit, becoming an astronaut.

## Discworld Gravity

From the *discworld* novels, you experience gravity like normal while on "top" of the disk and then no gravity when you fall off. This makes me wonder how the disk, elephants, and turtle all stay together. I'll have to go to the Unseen University to figure that out. I have read a little about their high-energy magic group doing some incredible things.

Comment: A flat world cannot have normal gravitation, or else it would be a spherical world; unless of course it is a very very small world.

Comment: @AlexP OR it is made of firmer (overall stiffer) stuff than every planet we have ever encountered so it keeps its disk shape. Additionally, I took it as a base assumption that such a world exists, never mind *how*, and the question is "what happens if you walk off?" Not "what happens if you walk off and can this exist?"

Comment: Discworld is perhaps best thought off as having it's primary source of gravity below the turtle or emanating from the turtle // if you step off the edge you fall, as do the seas which create the great rim waterfall, there's rather a lot of in world testament to that fact // precisely what Pratchett's' model for its gravity really is I'm not sure but you certainly don't float when you step off, not right away anyhow // he probably didn't worry about sensible predictable mechanics anyway, the whole thing relies on big magic after all, he may have just had it do what he wanted where he wanted.

Comment: @Pelinore Per the *Color of Magic*, he didn't really seem to care!

Comment: @PipperChip [You might like this](https://ianstewartjoat.weebly.com/orbital-mechanics.html) // the Google search string was *'Discworld gravity and orbital mechanics'*

Comment: @Pelinore THANK YOU! :D

Answer (score 2):

I have not read much on the subject, in fact, a few years ago when I started to learn this is even a thing, I thought it was just a bunch of dumb memes going around. When I finally realized people actually think this, I was a bit shocked.

From what I gleamed off the more basic info, (although there are some "smart" people trying to work out how the physics works), is basically down is down and gravity works only in the down direction. So if you came to the edge and walked off, you would fall in the down direction relative to the disc you left.

I have not read too much into this, but it would seem you could never achieve orbit because gravity will always act in one direction.

I would suggest not think too much on the true physics, as it doesn't actually work that way.